# Folder created by MSM not being removed on uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer, merge-module

I have an .MSI file created using VS2008. This .MSI is composed of a collection of merge modules, each of which basically installs one component of our application to its own folder.

When I try and uninstall the .MSI one of the subfolders created by a particular merge module is not removed, even if the application has not been run.

Any ideas why this may be ?

Interestingly a sub-folder underneath the un-removed folder is removed successfully. The un-removed folder and all of its contents can be deleted manually.

TIA

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - I had the path ModuleRetargetablePath set to the wrong default in the MSM project.